# how to pass the content of option element in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select onchange="showResult(this.value)">
    <option value="AAA">London</option>
    <option value="BBB">France</option>
    <option value="ccc">Berlin</option>
    <option value="DDD">Rome</option>
</select>
```

In above code, the value of each `<option>` has been passed as parameter in `showResult()`.

My questions is how to pass the content of option element (i.e.'London','France', 'Berlin', 'Rome') as parameter in `showResult()`.

Many Thanks

Comment: you should pick one answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

`[yourselect].options[0].text` returns 'London', `[yourselect].options[1].text` France, etc. So, in other words, for every option of an `options`-nodeList the property `text` contains its content.

Comment: yup, and here's an official reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_text.asp

Answer (score 1):

write this code

```
<select onchange="showResult(this.options[this.selectedIndex])">
    <option value="AAA">London</option>
    <option value="BBB">France</option>
    <option value="ccc">Berlin</option>
    <option value="DDD">Rome</option>
</select>
```

so you will pass the whole selected option node to the `showResult` function and you will be able to access both the value and text

```
function showResult(opt) {
    alert(opt.value);     /* e.g. DDD */
    alert(opt.text);      /* e.g. Rome */
}
```

Example Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xypGa/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.options[this.selectedIndex].text, been a while since I did this without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showResult()
{
   var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   var content = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this question about your issue - [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) ?

in general - `document.FORM.FIELDMANE.options[document.FORM.FIELDMANE.selectedIndex].value`

in your case it should be i suppose - `onchange="showResult(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `this.value` (the `value` property of the `select` element), pass `this` (the `select` element), i.e. `onchange="showResult(this)"`, and use code like

```
function showResult(selectElem) {
  var optionText = selectElem.options[selectElem.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(optionText); // replace by real code that uses the string
}
```

An added advantage is that now the function has access to the entire element, so that if you later need to use the `value` property, too, in the function, you can do that without modifying the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="showResult(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
    <option value="AAA">London</option>
    <option value="BBB">France</option>
    <option value="ccc">Berlin</option>
    <option value="DDD">Rome</option>
</select>
```